# How do I add a className to a div tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

See my code below:

```js
var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
    newcontent.innerHTML = 'draggable';
    newcontent.className = 'myclass';
    document.body.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);
```

Comment: For append the div to document body you should use `newcontent` itself instead of `.firstChild` - `document.body.appendChild(newcontent)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to append `newcontent`, Currently you are appending `newcontent.firstChild` which is a text node thus css class has no impact.

```js
var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
    newcontent.innerHTML = 'draggable';
    newcontent.className = 'myclass';
    document.body.appendChild(newcontent);
```

```css
.myclass {
  color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perfectly fine. But you should declare your css class in your code, so that it will picked correctly by the element.

```
.myclass {
  color: red
}
```

Here goes your code:

```
    var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
    newcontent.innerHTML = 'draggable';
    newcontent.className = 'myclass';
    document.body.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body" ).append("<div class='myclass'>draggabble</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can try this